# Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, flutter, build

What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project *:app' > Could not get unknown property "flutter for project *:app of type org-gradle.api.Project. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights * Get more help at help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 1s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code Exited (sigterm)

> No terminal:
> flutter clean;
> flutter packages pub cache repair

Answer (score 1):

The following properties resolved this for me.

In `android/local.properties` add:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=30
```